# Starting issue with UCBLogo

Tags: command-line, language-support

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS inside 64 bit machines.

Also, I often use Logo programming language.

Since a while (I'm not sure when this issue started), I get this rare characters each time I start UCBLogo (the native Linux app, installed from Synaptic Packages Manager):

[image: Rare characters UCBLogo starting screen]

Of course, I can change it, manually, with the UCBLogo panel menu (Fonts).

But... Why is this?

What's wrong, here?

How can I avoid this rare behaviour?

Comment: Seems to be fonts issue. Needs further investigation. Runs well out the box on MATE.

Comment: @N0rbert , Can I do something about this?

Comment: I can't reproduce on fresh minimal 20.04 LTS VM with only openbox installed and four font-packages. Which locale do you use? Please share the output of `locale` and upload output of `dpkg -l | grep -i font` to the pastebin. Do you see the rare characters instead of "Welcome to Berkeley Logo Version 6.1"?

Comment: @N0rbert, the output from the dpkg command is too big to paste here, I have a lot of fonts in my system. Whatever, I always get the same rare characters each time I start UCBLogo, here.

Comment: Since I upgraded my whole system to 22.04.1 LTS, it was fixed without my "hand".

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that producing a startup.lg file in my /home/username directory with the single line "setfont [Sans Regular]" (WITHOUT the quotes !) does the job of replacing the strange Unicode rectangles with the prescribed font. Including this line in /usr/bin/ however didn't function. The info given in the "startup" chapter of Briam Harvey's "UCBLOGO.usermanual.pdf" rhough it was helpful did NOT suffice: you SHOULD not include the line above into "to" ... "end" as I (misunderstanding the advice in the manual) did.

Comment: This issue is not present since I upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS.