# ucblogo doesn't execute startup.lg

Tags: fonts

Trying to solve
[Starting issue with UCBLogo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357468/starting-issue-with-ucblogo)
by adding a startup.lg file with the command "setfont [Sans Regular]" included, ucblogo doesn't execute it on startup though I put it into logolib as explained in "ucblogo.pdf". What goes ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that producing a startup.lg file in my /home/*username* directory with the single line
"setfont [Sans Regular]" (WITHOUT the quotes !)
does the job of replacing the strange Unicode rectangles with the prescribed font. Including this line in /usr/bin/ however didn't function.
The info given in the "startup" chapter of Briam Harvey's "UCBLOGO.usermanual.pdf" rhough it was helpful did NOT suffice: you SHOULD not include the line above into "to" ... "end" as I (misunderstanding the advice in the manual) did.